# checking if condition matches any value of an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, if-statement

What would be the best way to check if a condition matches any value in array?

So for example I want to implement a retry logic if there is a 5xx error received.

```
  var searchUserRequest = httpClient.request(searchUserRequestOptions, (res => {
    if(res.statusCode ===  500 || res.statusCode ===  501 || res.statusCode ===  502) {
      process.stdout.write('HELLO!!!!!! ');

      }

  }));
```

ideally I would like to put all the 5xx error does in a list or an array and then check if the res.status code equals any of the 5xx error codes.

What is the best way to do this in Javascript? Can I do this without a loop?

Comment: Maby `res.statusCode >= 500` ?

Comment: divide by 100 and check if quotient is 5. `Math.floor(statusCode/100)`

Comment: `[500,501,503].indexOf(res.statusCode) !=-1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just check to see if the `statusCode` is between 500 and 511 (that looks to be the [range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_errors))? An array is overkill.

```
var searchUserRequest = httpClient.request(searchUserRequestOptions, (res => {
  if(res.statusCode >= 500 && res.statusCode <= 511) {
    process.stdout.write('HELLO!!!!!! ');
  }
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

> ideally I would like to put all the 5xx error does in a list or an
>   array and then check if the res.status code equals any of the 5xx
>   error codes.

You can convert the `statusCode` to string and check if it starts with 5

```js
var searchUserRequest = httpClient.request(searchUserRequestOptions, (res => {
  if (res.statusCode.toString().startsWith('5')) {
    process.stdout.write('HELLO!!!!!! ');

  }
}));
```

Alternatively you can also use aobject literal to store statusCode as code and a corresponding message

```js
let statusCodes = {
  501: 'someMsg for 501',
  502: 'someMsg for 502',
  503: 'someMsg for 503',
}


var searchUserRequest = httpClient.request(searchUserRequestOptions, (res => {
  if (statusCodes[res.statusCode]) {
    process.stdout.write('HELLO!!!!!! ');

  }
}));
```

Another option is to keep all the status codes in a Map

```js
var statusCodesMap = new Map();
statusCodesMap.set(501, "value associated with 'a 501'");
statusCodesMap.set(502, 'value associated with 502');
statusCodesMap.set(503, 'value associated with 503');

var searchUserRequest = httpClient.request(searchUserRequestOptions, (res => {
  if (statusCodesMap.get(res.statusCode)) {
    process.stdout.write('HELLO!!!!!! ');
  }
}));
```

Comment: I like the second approach but `statusCodes[res.statusCode]` would have done the same in this case

Comment: @nickzoum good catch thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need ES5 compatible code you could use `Array#indexOf` (returns the index of the element in the array or -1 if the element does not exist in the array) for example:

```
var searchUserRequest = httpClient.request(searchUserRequestOptions, (res => {
    if([500, 501, 502].indexOf(res.statusCode) !== -1) {
        process.stdout.write('HELLO!!!!!! ');
    }
}));
```

If you can use ES7 you could use `Array#includes`:

```
var searchUserRequest = httpClient.request(searchUserRequestOptions, (res => {
    if([500, 501, 502].includes(res.statusCode)) {
        process.stdout.write('HELLO!!!!!! ');
    }
}));
```

If you are certain that will not need to check for any values that are in the 500s you could just use `500<= statusCode && statusCode < 600` as CertainPerformance suggested or use regular expressions: `/^5\d{2}$/.test(statusCode)`